# Creating swag and access to artwork

Tags: discussion, swag

Couple questions for those who have been around the network longer.

1. Are we allowed to create our own swag?
2. If we are allowed what all artwork do we have available to us?

Comment: We ***must*** petition SE for permission to get some merch made ...

Answer (score 8):

We are not allowed to use SE design elements without permission.  From the [guidelines](http://stackexchange.com/legal/trademark-guidance):

> Merchandise/Manufactured Items
>
> We generally do not permit use of our name or logo on merchandise.
>
> Do contact Stack Exchange Inc. with a detailed proposal if you would like to request an exception.
> Do not use the names or logos owned by Stack Exchange Inc. on any apparel or merchandise without our permission.

They say "logo" here, but I believe that would apply to all elements of the design -- putting the robot on a t-shirt probably won't fly.  Notice that the footer of every page includes this:

> site design / logo © 2016 Stack Exchange Inc; user contributions licensed under cc by-sa 3.0 with attribution required

When Mi Yodeya started its [publications project](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1568/472), we asked for and were granted permission to use the logo, including in an altered form for one publication.  (An SE designer even helped us with implementation.)  So permission can be obtained, but you need to ask and it sounds like conventional applications like t-shirts might be declined.  Something more closely tied with the site might be allowed, as it was for Mi Yodeya; that's up to SE.

Comment: Thanks Monica.  I am going to check in to how ludicrously expensive it would be to get a small batch of moleskine notebooks made up with some of the artwork on it...and then I can submit the proposal, ill make sure to share with everyone first.

Comment: @James Other sites have got notebooks as part of their official swag (UX certainly, I *think* others have as well) so there's a good chance that it would be included here. If it wasn't in the original announcement you could make a case for it to be included.

Comment: @ChrisF in the "updated design" post Kurtis said that one of the swag items would be a sketch pad with the poster art.  It's a shame the SE doesn't have a swag store any more, because I suspect that  more than the top 72 users will want those and would happily pay.

Comment: @MonicaCellio - cool (for those that qualify :) ). I should have checked there before commenting!

Answer (score 6):

So I filled out the contact us form asking about swag, and got this reply back:

> Hello,
>
> We create swag for every site once its design has been launched, and it will be sent to the top 72 users of the site once the swag designs have been finalized. You'll see a post about it on meta once it's ready, and we will contact all the eligible users to request shipping information.
>
> Regards,
> Stack Overflow Team

Comment: [Users 37-72](http://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users?page=2&tab=reputation&filter=all) currently.  Basically anyone on that page or with more rep.

Comment: So given that I'm currently languishing on [page 19](http://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users?page=19&tab=reputation&filter=all) I don't stand a hope in a really hot place of getting any :(

Comment: @ChrisF The email doesn't say exactly, but it's possible that they will also sell it once the design is finalized. Personally, I'd wait until that happens, and then use the contact us form to ask how much and where to buy one. You have some time though... ask and answer a bunch of questions. You only have to get 3500 more points, which is a possibility!

Comment: Cool! But how do they "contact us" (I just checked, and I seem to be #11 on WB) when there's no private message feature by design?

Comment: @JDługosz that's a good question, but there are systems for SE to communicate to people that we can't use, like the messages they sent before and during the elections. Having never been a part of a site graduation I don't know. Being at #22 last I checked I'm excited to find out!

Comment: Uh oh, now I have to make sure to keep in the top 72 to get swag :/

Comment: @Aify Eh, you should be OK if you keep some activity so as to not stand still, and there isn't a lot of people with massive runs of rep.

Comment: Well, it's not like I'm standing still at all, I'm actively doing stuff on the site, just nothing that would get me rep T.T Soon though, I'll have an awesome question!

Comment: @Aify Same, I'm on this site frequently but I mostly just vote, edit, or comment on things.

Comment: @fi12 I guess you could either just keep an eye out for when they finalize the design and see if it is, or use the contact us form now to ask if they will be selling it anywhere when the design is finalized. If you do contact them, let us know what they say!