# Community (non graduation) swag concepts and proposal

Tags: discussion, swag

So, [we can get swag made](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3566/creating-swag-and-access-to-artwork), ***beyond the graduation presents*** provided to high reputation users, with approval from the SO overlords. (That is obviously meant to be complimentary)  [Here are the specifics](http://stackexchange.com/legal/trademark-guidance).

So I have a couple ideas for community swag that I have been thinking of, I am going to post each idea as an answer and invite others to post ideas as answers as well.

**Post each swag idea as a single post**, and include the following information (if you don't have all the information at this time that is ok we can add it in later.)

**Feel free to offer art suggestions/changes in the comments of each answer**

- Object being created
- Art being used (this could take some work)
- Cost per item
- Minimum order quantity
- Other?

Comment: God, I just love looking at our design. The colours, the theme .. it's all simply gorgeous.

Answer (score 12):

**Product:**  Moleskine notebook:  http://www.moleskine.com/us/

**Art:**

Option 1:  Main site, robot and explorer on the outside front cover and perhaps the city in the background on an inside cover.

Options 2:  Site logo (globe with ring) stamped into the front cover and then put the site background (poster) on the inside of the cover.

**Other information:**

I submitted an inquiry to moleskine to figure out what kind of quantities and cost we are talking about, making sure to mention that we would have to get approval from the SE folks before we could get them made.

Comment: I think a blank book is especially suitable for this site. Even though not entirely for writers, RPG and whatnot also make notes, and WB is inherently *creative* no matter the purpose.

Comment: Did you ever hear back on pricing?

Answer (score 5):

**Product:**  Hoodie (in a couple of different colours)

**Art 1:**  A large WB globe on the front, with the "Worldbuilding" written underneath

**Art 2:**  Site logo as it is right now (Worldbuilding with the planet and ring)

**Art 3:** The robot/traveler and castle in the distance scene on the front

**Other information:** -- will look at options and get back to you --

Answer (score 3):

**Product:**  Stress globe

**Art:**  The same globe used in the icon and logo.  Only bigger.  Or just the logo.

**Other information:**

Possible vendor:  http://www.officeplaygroundprinting.com/cyber-gel-stress-ball-p5364.html

I have found that similar products can help bleed off nervous energy and support thinking.  Cheap when bought in bulk.

Comment: @AndreiROM James can correct me if I've misunderstood, but I think this post is to collect ideas for swag that would come from within the community, so people could do any number of these depending on reactions and practicality.  The swag that comes from SE is separate; SE decides what that will be.  (Which makes sense; it's their gift to us, after all.)  And *everything* on this meta thread would depend on somebody from the community organizing the effort and getting SE's permission.

Comment: @MonicaCellio - that changes things considerably.

Answer (score 2):

**Product:** Scale model of the robot and/or explorer.

**Art:**  Models of the two characters.

We would need someone to generate 3d models for printing but I am guessing with the proliferation of 3d printers we could probably find someone to do this.

**If you familiar with a vendor that supports this please post in the comments.**

**Other information:**

This one is still in concept mode, I do not have any size or vendor information at this time.

Comment: There's an SE site for 3D printing now, so maybe you could ask about vendors in their chat room?  Or, for all I know, it could be a FAQ on their site, so you might look there.  (I haven't.)

Comment: @MonicaCellio I hadn't heard about that site, Ill check it out.

Comment: One of my old friends is in the 3D printing business, I believe, so I'll see if I can get in touch.

Comment: @ArtOfCode that would be awesome

Answer (score 0):

**Product:**  T-Shirt

**Art:**  Logo on the front; message and background elements on the back.

**Other information:**

Slogan:  You dream it.  We help make the details feel real.

Comment: I don't like the slogan because I don't want to feel like a walking advertisement. I'd wear the logo and design because I love the community and theme.