# Swag for top 72 users?

Tags: discussion, swag

On this meta question, [Creating swag and access to artwork](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3566/creating-swag-and-access-to-artwork), we were discussing the possibility of creating merch for Worldbuilding to send out to the top 72 users of the site. For those who aren't in the top 72 like me, (I'm around~200), are we out of luck? Is there any way to get the swag unless we are part of the top 72 by rep, or will the products go on sale later on?

Answer (score 7):

We are not discussing what *SE* will send out; they get to decide that.  It's their gift to the top 72 users by rep; they don't make it generally available.

[Elsewhere on meta](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3572/28) people are talking about *other* swag, like you are, that would be produced by community members with SE permission.  Presumably such swag would be available to anybody who wants to buy it.